# Member reference base type 'Point *' is not a structure or union?

Tags: c++

```
class Point {

public:
    Point() : m_w(1) {}
    Point(uint32_t i, uint32_t j, double_t v) : m_i(i), m_j(j), m_v(v), m_w(1) {}

    double_t m_i;
    double_t m_j;
    double_t m_v;
    double_t m_w;
};

void Cz_Image_Processing::doSomethingWithCameras()
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    std::vector<Point*> v_error;
    Point *error_plane = new Point;
    // for different loop , different error and plane

    file_stream1 << plane << "," << error << std::endl;
    error_plane->m_i = error;
    error_plane->m_j = plane;
    v_error.push_back(error_plane);

    auto min = std::min_element(v_error.begin(), v_error.end(),
        [](const Point *a, const Point *b)
    {
        return (a->m_i < b->m_i);
    });

    std::cout << min->m_i; // error -Member reference base type 'Point *' is not a structure or union?
}
```

My question is -

I was trying to find the minimum error and also the plane associated with it- but while trying to do it it is showing the reference based type is not structure or union. I have read all the related answer but could not find the error.

Comment: The function doesn't return what you think it does: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element

Comment: I have used   std::cout << * min->m_i; it does not help

Comment: You need to include the parentheses around `min`, since `*min->m_i` is equivalent to `*(min->m_i)` which isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @NathanOliver do you have any suggestion  what should be the proper way ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `std::min_element()` returns an iterator to the min element. You should try something like: `(*min)->m_i`.

Comment: Thank you , it is now working but is not returning the minimum value , any idea why ??

Comment: For one, you only add one element to `v_error` in function `doSomethingWithCameras()`, so it will always be the minimum element.